# The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I get the following error when I run this command on headless ubuntu 20.04

```
selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=chrome chromeOptions.args=[disable-infobars, headless]" myproject.side

info:    Running Mynew.side
 FAIL  MySuiteOne/MytestOne.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
      (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
      (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

      at Object.throwDecodedError (../../usr/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (../../usr/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:560:13)
      at Executor.execute (../../usr/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:486:26)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.255s
Ran all test suites.
```

My Chrome version:91.0.4472.77 installed in /usr/bin/google-chrome
Chrome driver version: chromedriver@90.0.1

I also tried commands

```
selenium-side-runner /path/to/your-project.side
selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=chrome chromeOptions.args=[headless, no-sandbox, disable-dev-shm-usage, disable-infobars] chromeOptions.binary='/usr/bin/google-chrome'" Mynew.side
```

But still, I am facing the same error. Is there any way to fix this. I am trying to configure selenium in Ubuntu 20.04 Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: Try updating to Chromedriver `91.0.4472.19`? https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=91.0.4472.19/

Comment: I installed chromedriver through npm command as given in the documentation of selenium.      "npm install -g chromedriver --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root". I tried "npm update chromedriver -g" but still, it is showing version 90. Also tried downloading the v91 zip package from the link and copied it to /usr/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/ location but still, the version is showing 90. How will I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Chromedriver Download page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads),

> If you are using Chrome version 91, please download [ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.19](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=91.0.4472.19/)

Comment: I installed chromedriver through npm command as given in the documentation of selenium.      npm install -g chromedriver --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root. I tried "npm update chromedriver -g" but still, it is showing version 90. How will I proceed